# Find the combinations of length N from a matrix, each element need to be from different row/column

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

In a n*n matrix, find all the combinations of length n, such that every element in a combinations is from different column and different row.

```
For 2*2 Matrix
00 01
10 10
The possible combinations are (00,10) and (10,01)

For 3*3 Matrix
00 01 02
10 11 12
20 21 22
The possible combinations are (00,11,22) (00,12,21) (10,01,22) (10,02,21) (20,01,12) (20,02,11)
```

I have written below code in java. This program creates all combinatoins of length n.

For 2*2 Matrix the program returns all combinations of length 2. ie 4*4 = 16 combinations
[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 10], [0, 11], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 10], [1, 11], [10, 0], [10, 1], [10, 10], [10, 11], [11, 0], [11, 1], [11, 10], [11, 11]]

I want to modify this program such the only combinations satisfying the above property need to be returned.

I have tried multiple modifications for the for loop (like below one). But none of them worked.

```
for (int j = 0; j < lengOfComb; j++)
```

Note:The arugments i,j passed to the function findCombinations are redundant.
I referred this [article](http://www.programcreek.com/2014/03/leetcode-combinations-java/) to code.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MatrixCombinations {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 4;
        int[][] multi = new int[n][n];

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                multi[i][j] = i * 10 + j;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                System.out.print(multi[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        ArrayList<Integer> current = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        findCombinations(multi, result, current, 0, 0, 0);
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("The lenght of the result array is " + result.size());

    }

    public static void findCombinations(int[][] input, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result, ArrayList<Integer> current,
            int lengOfComb, int m, int n) {
        int size = input.length;

        if (lengOfComb == size) {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(current);
            result.add(temp);
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                current.add(input[i][j]);
                findCombinations(input, result, current, lengOfComb + 1, i, j);
                current.remove(current.size() - 1);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This basically boils down to generate all [permutations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation) of length `n`. For each permutation `p`, the matching result of your "matrix combination" is `{ M[0][p[0]], M[1][p[1]], ..., m[n-1][p[n-1]] }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're approach is way to complicated.
Basically this problem can as well be expressed this way:
Find all permutations of length n of numbers in range `[0 , n)`. These permutations can then be translated into the searched combinations by combining the permutations with the range `[0 , n)` to a set of pairs, which can be used as indices in the matrix:

```
int[] permutation = generatePermutation(int n);
int[] combination = new int[n];

for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    combination[i] = matrix[i][permutation[i]];
```

Basically all you'd then need to do is generate all permutations of the numbers in `[0 , n)` and apply the above algorithm to find the permutations:

EDIT: sorry for the incorrect permutation-generator, I was a bit distracted and in a hurry when i posted this. Here's a correct generator using the Steinhaus-Johnson-Trotter-Algorithm:

```
void generatePermutations(List<Integer> permutation , int n){
    if(n == -1){
        for(int i = 0 ; i < permutation.size() ; i++)
            System.out.print(matrix[i][permutation.get(i)]);
        System.out.println();
    }else{
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= permutation.size() ; i++){
            permutation.add(i , n);
            generatePermutations(permutation , n - 1);
            permutation.remove(i);
        }
    }
}
```

A test-run with this matrix:

```
matrix = new String[][]{
    {"a1" , "b1" , "c1"} ,
    {"a2" , "b2" , "c2"} ,
    {"a3" , "b3" , "c3"}
};
```

Produces this output:

> a1b2c3
>   b1a2c3
>   b1c2a3
>   a1c2b3
>   c1a2b3
>   c1b2a3

Comment: Thank you. Very elegant approach.

Comment: @mc20 glad to help you. Btw., sry for the mistake i made with the permutation-generator, I wrote the code in haste and made a mistake. I've edited the post with a correct generator.